# Matrix calculations in rails app

Tags: ruby, matrix

In my rails app I need to do the following:

1. Create a form for inputting the data for a 4x4 matrix, store this data in a model
2. Use a ruby matrix for calculating the cholesky decomposition of this matrix, and then displaying the resulting decomposed matrix in a view

From what I understand the form data is stored in a 1-dimensional array, I need the data stored in a 4x4 array but I haven't seen any examples of this. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the following tools:

- standard [Matrix class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html)
- [ruby gsl](http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/) gem
- [extendmatrix](https://github.com/clbustos/extendmatrix) gem